# Do not understand locals in rails - getting a No method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am fairly new to rails and I am trying to the shopping cart html view to the site admin when a order is made. The email portion is working just fine with simple html but when I add the ruby code to render the views page I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Charges#create
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/order_mailer/order_email.html.erb where line #7 raised:

undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #7):
5
6
7



<%= render "carts/shopping_cart",  size: @order_items.size  %>

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/order_mailer/order_email.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_order_mailer_order_email_html_erb___1590505826361550286_70123907983000'
app/mailers/order_mailer.rb:11:in `order_email'
app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

From what I have read I think I need to add locals to my render code but I am confused on what exactly locals are and what they would be in my code. If I am completely off track and this error has nothing to do with locals I would appreciate some guidance in the right direction.

Thanks!

order_email view:

```
<h1>You have a new order </h1>
<%= render "carts/shopping_cart",  size: @order_items.size  %>
```

The view I am trying to render in the email:

```
<% if !@order_item.nil? && @order_item.errors.any? %>
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
        <% @order_item.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <% if @order_items.size == 0 %>
      <p class="text-center">
        There are no items in your shopping cart.  Please <%= link_to "go back", root_path %> and add some items to your cart.
      </p>
    <% else %>
      <% @order_items.each do |order_item| %>
        <%= render 'carts/cart_row', product: order_item.product, order_item: order_item, show_total: true %>
      <% end %>
```

order_mailer.rb:

```
class OrderMailer < ApplicationMailer

  default from: "xxxx@gmail.com"

  def order_email(order_items)
    @order_items = order_items

       mail(to: "xxxx@gmail.com", subject: "Your subject")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe locals are only used when doing a render partial, which you should be able to do for this but you'd need to make a few adjustments.

Each of the partials' filename need to be adjusted to have and underscore in front of them, but you still reference them without the underscore (I know it's a bit confusing).

So rename `carts/shopping_cart` to `carts/_shopping_cart`
and then change where it's referenced to:

`<%= render partial: "carts/shopping_cart",  locals:{size: @order_items.size}  %>`

Do the same sort of thing with 'carts/cart_row'